# Проблема с длительным парсингом

Tags: php

Есть PHP скрипт, который парсит 32 000 страниц и полученные данные отправляет в БД МУСКУЛА. 
Проблема - автозавершение работы скрипта браузером.
Пробовал ставить более долгое время исполнение скрипта, но работает некорректно.

Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Парсите блоками.

Comment: А в чём вопрос? "Как запустить этот скрипт без помощи браузера?" Или, наборот, вам нужно чтобы все браузеры всегда дожидались результатов работы этого скрипта?

Comment: Вопрос в том - как сделать так, чтобы скрипт не автозавершался браузером. Либо выполнился, даже при автозавершении. Ну впринципе, ответ ниже дали. Как-то не додумался формировать массив и только потом отправлять в мускул. Ведь у меня цикл в 2000 раз и каждый раз отправляются данные в мускул.

Comment: Браузер не завершает работу скрипта...

Answer (score 1):

Формировать массив или какой-то пакет и потом отправлять массово в БД.

Comment: Можете добавить код со [схожего вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql) из англоязычного SO.